# JS + PHP - delete specific cookie

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

I am having trouble deleting a specific cookie in Chrome, debugger is not picking up anything at all, although this is the same code found in another SO thread

reset.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Option 1 - set cookie to null
    //$.cookie('welcome_<?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?>', null);

    // Option 2 - delete specific cookie
    delete_cookie('welcome_<?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?>');

    // relocate back to index.php
    window.location = 'index.php';
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried to both directly delete the cookie via `delete_cookie` and also to set the cookie to `null`, both without result.

I am not good with JavaScript, would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction. Must be something simple.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the delete_cookie function?

Comment: There is no such php function called `delete_cookie()`. If you want to delete a cookie you'd have to `setcookie()` to the past. You also need to remember that cookies are client-specific, so you can't delete person X's cookies unless they access the page.

Answer (score 2):

I use something called JSCookie. You can easily do `Cookies.remove('Cookie_name');` in JavaScript!

1. [JSCookie Repository](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/)

2. [JSCookie Download](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/download/v2.1.3/js.cookie-2.1.3.min.js)

Comment: @Armitage2k Fun fact! CookiesJS used to be a jQuery plugin, but separated and now it's just it's own JavaScript library which makes managing cookies a lot easier! You can do `Cookies.set('cookie', 1, {expires: 6});`, `Cookies.remove('cookie');`, and `Cookies.get('cookie');`

Answer (score 1):

You can delete your cookie using javascript by setting expiration date to time less than current time like below-

```
 document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
```

and you can delete cookie using php to -

```
 unset($_COOKIE['cookiename']);
 // or you may also remove cookie by setting cookie less than current time 
 setcookie('cookiename', null, time()-3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:3 functions to set,get and delete cookies

```
 function setCookie(key, value) {           

            document.cookie = key + '=' + value;
        }

 function getCookie(key) {
            var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
            return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
        }

function delete_cookie(name) {
          document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
```

**A clean way to delete a cookie is to clear both of `$_COOKIE` value and browser cookie file :**

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['key'])) {
    unset($_COOKIE['key']);
    setcookie('key', '', time() - 3600, '/'); // empty value and old timestamp
}
```

Set the value to "" and the expiry date to yesterday (or any date in the past)

```
setcookie("hello", "", time()-3600);
```

Then the cookie will expire the next time the page loads.